# Loading a model into the 2D/3D viewer - Autodesk Forge

Tags: node.js, autodesk, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to run the Autodesk `viewer-navigation.sample` [link](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/viewer-navigation.sample) on my machine but I get just a loading screen and nothing happens.

I think it's because I haven't loaded the model, I'm not sure I understand what it means to do:

> To prepare the models, run the Initial Setup endpoint.

But when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/forge/initialsetup when the server is running I get: `Cannot GET /forge/initialsetup`

I did set in the Autoforge app the callback url to be `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth`

I also did run:

```
npm install
set FORGE_CLIENT_ID=<<YOUR CLIENT ID FROM DEVELOPER PORTAL>>
set FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=<<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>>
```

What else can be done to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, till we'll fix it, you could try either define a FORGE_BUCKET env variable:

`set FORGE_BUCKET=someuniquename2d3d`

or within source code (forge.js) change the line 45:

`var ossBucketKey = process.env.FORGE_BUCKET || 'navigationsample3d2d';`

by replacing the ***'navigationsample3d2d'*** string with something like ***'someveryuniquename2d3d'***.

This should work.

Comment: Those 2 strings are the same, maybe you meant "someuniquename2d3d"? I think it works now, I need to check if I can show my own models.

Comment: I can show the sample models that come in the repo but not my own models, even if I change the names in the forge.js file and run the initial setup... How can I change the models?

Comment: @kuhaku: Thanks, fixed the string.

Comment: Keep in mind, that this is just a sample. If you want just to check your model in it, the best way is to put it into samples folder and rename it into either ```rac_basic_sample_project.rvt``` or ```rac_advanced_sample_project.rvt``` and it will be picked up by the sample upon access of ```initialsetup```.

Comment: If you have more than 2 models, you can edit the lines 75-76 from the forge.js file and add them by hand as illustrated there.
In the end, if you want to have a more solid approach, then you can replace the mentioned lines with a function that will scan the sample folder and upload the found models, but here you will have to deal with task like filtering the useless files (hidden, temporary etc) and other things.
This is why we keep the provided samples as simple as possible, but with room for further improvement.